# Initial deployment of Community Cloud plagued by errors

Tags: community, deployment, customer-community, lightning-community, community-builder

We are attempting to deploy a brand new customer Community Cloud Site from a Sandbox to Production, using Change Sets, and are encountering some errors that have Salesforce Tier3 support scratching their heads.

The latest error from the 477-component Change Set:

Component Error Message:

Implement "forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" for the Aura component forceCommunity:themeSearch with ID 68de04b2-29e8-435a-846d-a97a5d1097f5 and try again.

API Name: Site_Name1
Type: Site.com

This is an error you'd usually see associated with custom Aura components. In our case, there are no custom components that reference "foreCommunity:themeSearch". And the only place we see it referenced is in the ExperienceBundle metadata.

Some background/things we've tried:

Template in use: Customer Account Portal
Theme: Jepson
Both orgs were recently updated to Summer '20 Release.
API version used by Change Sets: 49 (latest)

The original blocker we experienced was this bug that Salesforce told us to "wait out" for the Release to drop. We waited several weeks and eventually got over that hump.
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000KTFxQAO&title=deployment-of-experiencebundle-component-is-getting-failed

I crawled the Known Issues log for potentially-related bugs. Found this that was related to the swap of the default Profile Menu component used in the template. https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KSxDQAW

We've gone through all standard and custom components that live on pages looking for anything "search" related, toggling values, etc.

What shall we try next?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `forceCommunity:themeProfileMenu`
https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9064S000000CmW5QAK. It appeared that I had 2 theme layouts which contained `forceCommunity:themeProfileMenu`. Initially I updated pages that used the "Default" theme layout with the new Customized User Profile component but the error persisted. Once I figured out that there was another theme layout "Home" with 1 page assigned, I updated the old User Profile on that page and everything worked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post. It's a good idea to look through the theme layouts for potential conflicts. I'll have a look and let you know if something good happens :).